# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import after update from Angular 8 to Angular 15

Tags: angular, sass

I am getting this error:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import '~src/scss/vars';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 3:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import '~src/scss/vars';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 3:9  root stylesheet

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - NGCC failed.
```

The project directory is like below:

```
ClientApp\
  node_modules\
  src\
    app\
    assets\
    environments
    scss\
      _vars.scss
    index.html
    main.ts
    style.scss
  angular.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  tslint.json
  yarn.lock
```

when I do >ng serve to compile in the ClientApp\ directory, it gave that error.

the '`style.scss`' has the `@import '~src/scss/vars';` line that is causing the error

I've tried several ways from SO postings to no avail. I don't want to use explicit path, so the question is that it seems the global `~src/scss/vars` is not recognized any more after update. I've tried putting the `stylePreprocessorOptions` in the options in the `angular.json`, still not working.

My `angular.json` is as below:

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "Consolidated": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "prefix": "app",
          "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
              "styleext": "scss"
            }
          },
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "progress": true,
                "outputPath": "dist",
                "outputHashing":  "all",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ],
                "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                  "includePaths": [
                    "src/scss"
                  ]
                },
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss",
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "src/assets/leaflet/leaflet.css",
                  "node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css",
                  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "src/assets/test_geo_data.js"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ],
                  "optimization": true,
                  "output-hashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "Consolidated:build"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "Consolidated:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "Consolidated:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": [],
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                  "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            },
            "server": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist-server",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "dev": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "output-hashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": true
                },
                "production": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "output-hashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Consolidated-e2e": {
          "root": "e2e/",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "Consolidated:serve"
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "defaultProject": "Consolidated"
    }
```

My package.json is as below:

```
{
  "name": "Consolidated",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Consolidated:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.6",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^15.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.2",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.30.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.9",
    "ngx-toastr": "^16.1.0",
    "open-iconic": "^1.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "~18.15.11",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```